# Is there an alternative way in Ext JS, like the jQuery .unwrap method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs

I could not find a alternative function to unwrap a element like you can do it using jQuery.
Is there another way to do this?

My goal is to archive this code and copy all of it's attribute to it's child element.
and remove the parent.

```
<div class="abc" myid="123" position="2">
<span class="someblock">
    <p>Some paragraph</p>
    <img width="140px; height: 140px;" class="myimg" src="http://www.urltoimage.com/image.png">
</span>
</div>
```

And the result should be:

```
<span class="someblock abc" myid="123" position="2">
<p>Some paragraph</p>
<img width="140px; height: 140px;" class="myimg" src="http://www.urltoimage.com/image.png" />
</span>
```

Thanks in advance, Chris.

Comment: Why don't you just use jQuery?

Comment: I am not allowed to include a second party library :(

Answer (score 4):

I always ship my ExtJS projects with jQuery to do such operations and I recommend you to do the same

It will make your life easier ;)

Edit:

If you strictly need to do it in ExtJS you will need a [`Ext.dom.Element`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.dom.Element) and operate on it. [`Ext.get('id')`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext-method-get) will provide you with one.

```
unwrap: function() {
    parent = this.parent().dom;
    this.insertBefore(parent );

    // code for copy the styles, classes & attributes here

    parent.destroy();
    return this;
}
```

> The method is supposed to be called on `Ext.dom.Element` class or any
>   one that extend it

Comment: I am not allowed to include a second party library :(

Comment: LOL hahaha, i could do that yes :)

Comment: @chriscrossweb Se my edit... And yes, you will need to implement this yourself. Even if ExtJS has a wrap method there is no unwrap

Comment: @chriscrossweb I posted a simple method that should unwrap a single element (and only that). You may need to apply any code for copying attributes, classes etc. but it should give you a start. Note: all untested!!

Comment: hi, thanks! 
I have made a fiddler of this: http://jsfiddle.net/UYVbY/
Don't know why I get a error: HierarchyRequestError: DOM Exception 3
Do you know why perhaps?

Comment: @chriscrossweb I think so, [working version](http://jsfiddle.net/UYVbY/1/) you used the `insertBefore()` method the wrong way. It need to be called by the child with the parent as argument, not vice verse

Comment: @sra when I use inspect element on the div, the parent div is still there and one of the div is even added on the body parent (after the header).

Comment: @chriscrossweb in Your example you will keep the div with the class `abc` The first has the body as parent and we should break if we meet the body as parent. Anyway nothing important will happen (except a invalid insertBefore call) the second is wrapped and the wrap get removed (`<div class="container">`) Note that unwrap is called on a children not the wrapping parent! If your goal is to keep just the the span tags you need to iterate over the spans not the divs. Anyway this [updated version](http://jsfiddle.net/UYVbY/3/) will skip the body tag. So basically I would say all works correct?

Answer (score 0):

Just use jQuery. It's the simplest way, since ExtJS is a User Interface toolkit it won't let you such low level operations. So first think about it. Do you really have to manipulate the DOM tree? If yes => deliver jQuery as well.

Edit:
Of course you could simply implement this particular function yourself *inspired* by the jQuery code ;)